# OrchardCMS Query Filtering On Specific Taxonomy Value

Tags: filter, content-management-system, orchardcms, taxonomy, projection

I have a Custom Content Type "Case Studies". one of the fields is a taxonomy.

Category ( Content Creation, Event Experiences, Experiential Design, Visual Communications)

I would like to filter on one of those values, and place that on a Page. using the projection content type. I can see how to filter on the existence of said taxonomy, in countless examples. But not on a specific value. i.e "Event Experiences", some where else filter on "Content Creation".

Comment: Is the `Has Terms` filter under `Taxonomy` what you need?

Comment: right there in front of my face. I've been looking at that box for 2 days and only seeing the Taxonomy Name. :/ Thank you very much.